# Django urls.py giving problems

Tags: python, django, apache

I have an application that is running on Django. Our urls.py had following entries -

```
url(r'^$', 'web.views.index', name='index'),
url(r'^g$', 'web.views.getpost', name='getpost'),

url(r'^p$', 'web.views.postarticle', name='postarticle'),
```

It was working fine for thes url patterns. However, I've added two more url patterns -

```
url(r'^d$', 'web.views.delete', name='delete'),

url(r'^u$', 'web.views.update', name='update'),
```

And it when I hit

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/d
```

It gives - The current URL, d, didn't match any of these.

I don't know why its not recognizing newly added url patterns. Any idea why its not working?

EDIT: As Wesley mentioned, it shows:

Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/d Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
^$ [name='index']
^g$ [name='getpost']
^p$ [name='postarticle']
```

It doesn't show ^d or ^u url patterns.

Here is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'web.views.index', name='index'),
    url(r'^g$', 'web.views.getpost', name='getpost'),

    url(r'^p$', 'web.views.postarticle', name='postarticle'),
url(r'^d$', 'web.views.delete', name='delete'),

    url(r'^u$', 'web.views.update', name='update'),
)
```

Comment: Make sure you restart your webserver.  You may have to kill some rogue python processes too.

Comment: I restarted my webserver..but no avail. I even restarted my machine. Still no result.

Comment: Has `^d$` line been listed below `The current URL, d, didn't match any of these.`?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that? Where it should be listed?

Comment: Wesley's answer is exactly what I mean

Comment: Yep, I've updated it! Any idea, whats going wrong?

Comment: Why not show the whole urls.py

Comment: Do you have any old .pyc or .pyo files? If so, try deleting them and then restarting the webserver.

Comment: Its a development server. So will restarting help?

Comment: Ok. So I've resolved the issue. I removed all the .pyc files. Restarted dev server and it all started working. No idea...why it wasn't working.

Comment: Ok, I'll add that as an answer so that other people with similar issues can see what fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the information you gave us. Both the url pattern and the url you try to visit look ok.

-> What does the debug view exactly return? Does is show:

> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/d
>   Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> ```
> ^ ^$ [name='index']
> ^ ^g$ [name='getpost']
> ^ ^p$ [name='postarticle']
> ^ ^d$ [name='delete']
> ^ ^u$ [name='update']
> ```

Probably the debug view either doesn't list the delete url, it show it with a typo, or the request url is a little different. Try to give us a little more information if you still can't figure out the problem!

Comment: I've updated my original post. Thanks for pointing it out. Any idea why its not showing?

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the comments to the question, the problem was a stale .pyc file. This was fixed by deleting the .pyc files and restarting the server.

In order to prevent this issue in future, you should remove .pyc files before starting a dev server. You can use the following command to quickly delete all pyc files in the current directory and all subdirectories (make sure to check that find returns the right files before killing them).

```
find . -name "*.pyc" #Find all pyc files and list them to console
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm '{}' ';' #Run command rm on each file found
```